# How to get Year-to-Date in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, data-manipulation

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I was wondering if there is a way to get Year-to-Date in python. I usually just filter for dates but this data updates on a daily basis and I want to make a bar chart in matplotlib that shows the number for sales for this Year-to-Date. Is this possible to get the Year-to-Date in pandas.

This is what I have tried so far but it didn't work:

`ytd = df.groupby([df.date.month, df.date.day, df.date.year]).distance.sum().unstack().cumsum()`

Can someone please help me get the YTD in pandas?

I am using the superstore data: [Superstore dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vivek468/superstore-dataset-final)

Comment: Can you please give more details on how your dataframe looks like?

Comment: @mcjeb the dataset is called the superstore dataset and it shows the superstore dataset which shows information on all of the sales, profit, quantity and etc. from the store and I will add the dataset into the question so everyone is able to download it and view it. Please let me know if this description and the dataset helps.

Comment: better show `minimal working code` with small example data in code.

Comment: if you get error then show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image). We can't run your code, we can't see your data, and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question.

Comment: @John Shecut Yes thats good seeing the dataset. I will try to write an answer

Answer (score 0):

I made a fictitious dataframe as an example. Use [dt.year](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) to get the year and check for equality with 2023. The result is all rows for 2023.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Order Date': ['11/8/2016', '11/5/2023',
                                  '6/12/2016',  '6/12/2023', '4/5/2015'],
                   'Sales': [47.04, 30.84, 226.56, 115.02, 78.304]})

df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], errors='raise')

df1 = df[df['Order Date'].dt.year == 2023]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  Order Date   Sales
1 2023-11-05   30.84
3 2023-06-12  115.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vivek468/superstore-dataset-final) really helped.

First its easier to convert the given date in the format month/day/year into a pandas datetime object:

`superstore['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(superstore['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')`

This now allows us to access the year part of each order that so we can take only the rows that have an order date in the desired year:

```
desired_year = 2017 # replace with desired year
ytd_data = superstore[superstore['Order Date'].dt.year == desired_year].copy()
```

Then we should set the index to 'Order Date', so that pandas knows what to form the cumsum over later:

```
# set index to the order date
ytd_data.set_index('Order Date', inplace=True)
```

Now we can form the cumsum to get the YTD sales. However first sum all sales for each day, so we get sales on a daily basis (so sum to date actually makes sense).

```
# Resample data on a daily basis and calculate cumulative sum
ytd_sales = ytd_data.resample('D')['Sales'].sum().cumsum()
```

So now we can use it to plot the histogram. I first defined the days in the year to use as x-axis:

```
days = np.arange(len(ytd_sales))
date_array = pd.to_datetime(days, unit='D', origin=f'{desired_year}-01-01')
```

And then plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.bar(date_array, ytd_sales, color='blue')
plt.title(f'Year-to-Date Sales in year {desired_year}')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Sales')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I then got the following output:

[image: ytd sales histogram for 2017]

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.